# Any C compiler to run C files?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ide

I have got some programs in C which I want to run. I have tried several different compilers such as BorlandC++, Turbo C but they don't seem to compile/run it. Some compilers don't recognize .c file and can only read .cpp files.
Can you please recommend me some C compiler and/or IDE for Windows 8 on which I can run these programs?

Comment: Try saying: _Run code run.  C code run._  That should do it.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable as you haven't revealed the error messages you are seeing, and what steps you are using in attempting to compile.  Also, does reading the source code or distribution notes discuss what compilers were used or recommended for this project?

Comment: A few compilers I used were unable to recognize the C file. I also used Borland C++ 5.5 from Embarcadero and it says "windows.h and stdio.h" not found even though they are in same directory where my code files are.

Comment: stdio.h, for example, is a standard library, and is unlikely to reside in your project's root directory.  It sounds like your compiler isn't properly installed, or not configured correctly, or not being used correctly, which is more about not knowing how to use the compiler or install it correctly than about finding a compiler that is tolerant of misconfiguration or misuse.

Comment: @FrankMartin:  The compiler will only look for files in the current folder if included like `#include "windows.h"`.  If you have `#include <windows.h>`, it will only search directories specified on the command line or via environment variables as include file folders.  I can't think of a single C++ compiler that does not also support C++ compilation.  You would do better to describe what you are trying to compile, the compiler you are using, the command line you are using to build it, and any messages output of the build. Obviously a C compiler will compile C code, so the problem is you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try the gcc compiler with cygwin. It runs almost everywhere and there are tons of tutorials. I think it's the most used C compiler ever.
http://gcc.gnu.org

Comment: Also MinGW/GCC will allow the use of the GNU compiler on Windows without the Cygwin Linux emulation layer.

Answer (score 1):

Those compilers you are talking about are really old. Try something newer: 
Visual studio: http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs
Mingw: http://www.mingw.org